# C++ Header / Dowhile loop

Tags: c++, header-files

Alright so at the moment Im working on this battleship program and I have 2 problems I havent been able to figure out for the past few hours.

1. The variable from the header file (shipsDestroyed, torpedoesLeft) wont be recognized in my do while loop.
2. Im not sure of a quick way to check if ship destroyed and not add 1 each time it checks.

Problem 1 Occurs in the Battleship.cpp, the game continues to loop even if torpedoes hits 0 or the ships hit 5.

Problem 2 Occurs in game.cpp, I have it set each time to +1 when a ships state is equal to being sunk, but it adds 1 every time the loop goes around.

MAIN.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include "battleship.h"

using namespace std;

//Start of main
int main()
{
    battleship B1;
    B1.newBattleship();
}//End of main
```

BATTLESHIP.H

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class battleship
{
protected:
    int shipsDestroyed;
    int torpedoesLeft;
public:
    void constructGame(int sd, int tL)
    {
        shipsDestroyed = sd;
        torpedoesLeft = tL;
    }

    void setShipsDestroyed(int sd)
    {
        shipsDestroyed = sd;
    }
    void setTorpedoesLeft(int tL)
    {
        torpedoesLeft = tL;
    }

    int getShipsDestroyed()
    {
        return shipsDestroyed;
    }
    int getTorpedoesLeft()
    {
        return torpedoesLeft;
    }

    void newBattleship();
    void newGame();
};
```

BATTLESHIP.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include "battleship.h"

#include "game.h"

using namespace std;

void battleship::newBattleship()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the game of Battleship!\n\n";
    battleship game;
    game.newGame();
}

void battleship::newGame()
{
    Game G1;

    G1.constructGame(0,45);

    G1.setupBoard();
    G1.outputBoard();

    do
    {
        G1.torpedoes();
        G1.outputBoard();
    }while((shipsDestroyed != 5) && (torpedoesLeft != 0));
}
```

GAME.H

```
class Game: public battleship
{   
protected:

public:
    string gameBoard[10][10];

    void setupBoard();
    void outputBoard();
    void torpedoes();
};
```

GAME.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "battleship.h"

#include "game.h"

using namespace std;

string gameBoard[10][10];

//Start of setupBoard
void Game::setupBoard()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x ++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 10; y ++)
        {
            gameBoard[x][y] = "?";
        }//End of Y for loop
    }//End of X for loop
}//End of setupBoard

void Game::outputBoard()
//Start of outputBoard
{   
    cout << "? = Unknown\n* = Miss\nX = Hit\n\n";

    cout << "    A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J\n";
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "1   " << gameBoard[0][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[0][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "2   " << gameBoard[1][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[1][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "3   " << gameBoard[2][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[2][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "4   " << gameBoard[3][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[3][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "5   " << gameBoard[4][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[4][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "6   " << gameBoard[5][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[5][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "7   " << gameBoard[6][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[6][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "8   " << gameBoard[7][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[7][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "9   " << gameBoard[8][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[8][9] << endl;
    cout << "  _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "10  " << gameBoard[9][0] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][1] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][2] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][3] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][4] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][5] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][6] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][7] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][8] << "  |  " << gameBoard[9][9] << endl;
    cout << "       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |\n" << endl;
}//End of outputBoard


//Start of torpedoes
void Game::torpedoes()
{
    //Holds Row
    int row = 0;
    //Holds column char
    char temp;
    //Holds Column
    int column = 0;

    //Start of torpedo and checks if torpedo is valid entry
    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose a row. (1 - 10)\n";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "\n";
    }while((row != 1) && (row != 2) && (row != 3) && (row != 4) && (row != 5) && (row != 6) && (row != 7) && (row != 8) && (row != 9) && (row != 10));      
    //Checks if torpedos end is valid entry
    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose a column. (A - J)\n";
        cin >> temp;
        cout << "\n";
    }while((temp != 'A') && (temp != 'a') && (temp != 'B') && (temp != 'b') && (temp != 'C') && (temp != 'c') && (temp != 'D') && (temp != 'd') && (temp != 'E') && (temp != 'e') && (temp != 'F') && (temp != 'f') && (temp != 'G') && (temp != 'g') && (temp != 'H') && (temp != 'h') && (temp != 'I') && (temp != 'i') && (temp != 'J') && (temp != 'j'));

    if((temp == 'A') || (temp == 'a'))
    {
        column = 0;
    }
    else if((temp == 'B') || (temp == 'b'))
    {
        column = 1;
    }
    else if((temp == 'C') || (temp == 'c'))
    {
        column = 2;
    }
    else if((temp == 'D') || (temp == 'd'))
    {
        column = 3;
    }
    else if((temp == 'E') || (temp == 'e'))
    {
        column = 4;
    }
    else if((temp == 'F') || (temp == 'f'))
    {
        column = 5;
    }
    else if((temp == 'G') || (temp == 'g'))
    {
        column = 6;
    }
    else if((temp == 'H') || (temp == 'h'))
    {
        column = 7;
    }
    else if((temp == 'I') || (temp == 'i'))
    {
        column = 8;
    }
    else if((temp == 'J') || (temp == 'j'))
    {
        column = 9;
    }


    //Output
    cout << "Row: " << row << endl;
    row = row - 1;
    cout << "Column: " << temp << endl;

    if((row == row) && (column == column))
    {
        gameBoard[row][column] = "*";
    }

    //Ship 1
    if((row == 0) && (column == 0))
    {
        //Row: 1 | Column: A
        gameBoard[0][0] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 0) && (column == 1))
    {
        //Row: 1 | Column: B
        gameBoard[0][1] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 0) && (column == 2))
    {
        //Row: 1 | Column: C
        gameBoard[0][2] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 0) && (column == 3))
    {
        //Row: 1 | Column: D
        gameBoard[0][3] = "X";
    }

    if((gameBoard[0][0] == "X") && (gameBoard[0][1] == "X") && (gameBoard[0][2] == "X") && (gameBoard[0][3] == "X"))
    {
        shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed + 1;
    }

    //Ship 2
    if((row == 4) && (column == 6))
    {
        //Row: 5 | Column: G
        gameBoard[4][6] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 5) && (column == 6))
    {
        //Row: 6 | Column: G
        gameBoard[5][6] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 6) && (column == 6))
    {
        //Row: 7 | Column: G
        gameBoard[6][6] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 7) && (column == 6))
    {
        //Row: 8 | Column: G
        gameBoard[7][6] = "X";
    }

    if((gameBoard[4][6] == "X") && (gameBoard[5][6] == "X") && (gameBoard[6][6] == "X") && (gameBoard[7][6] == "X"))
    {
        shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed + 1;
    }

    //Ship 3
    if((row == 3) && (column == 9))
    {
        //Row: 4 | Column: J
        gameBoard[3][9] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 4) && (column == 9))
    {
        //Row: 5 | Column: J
        gameBoard[4][9] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 5) && (column == 9))
    {
        //Row: 6 | Column: J
        gameBoard[5][9] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 6) && (column == 9))
    {
        //Row: 7 | Column: J
        gameBoard[6][9] = "X";
    }

    if((gameBoard[3][9] == "X") && (gameBoard[4][9] == "X") && (gameBoard[5][9] == "X") && (gameBoard[6][9] == "X"))
    {
        shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed + 1;
    }

    //Ship 4
    if((row == 9) && (column == 2))
    {
        //Row: 10 | Column: C
        gameBoard[9][2] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 9) && (column == 3))
    {
        //Row: 10 | Column: D
        gameBoard[9][3] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 9) && (column == 4))
    {
        //Row: 10 | Column: E
        gameBoard[9][4] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 9) && (column == 5))
    {
        //Row: 10 | Column: F
        gameBoard[9][5] = "X";
    }

    if((gameBoard[9][2] == "X") && (gameBoard[9][3] == "X") && (gameBoard[9][4] == "X") && (gameBoard[9][5] == "X"))
    {
        shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed + 1;
    }

    //Ship 5
    if((row == 3) && (column == 1))
    {
        //Row: 4 | Column: B
        gameBoard[3][1] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 4) && (column == 1))
    {
        //Row: 5 | Column: B
        gameBoard[4][1] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 5) && (column == 1))
    {
        //Row: 6 | Column: B
        gameBoard[5][1] = "X";
    }
    if((row == 6) && (column == 1))
    {
        //Row: 7 | Column: B
        gameBoard[6][1] = "X";
    }

    if((gameBoard[3][1] == "X") && (gameBoard[4][1] == "X") && (gameBoard[5][1] == "X") && (gameBoard[6][1] == "X"))
    {
        shipsDestroyed = shipsDestroyed + 1;
    }

    system("cls");

    torpedoesLeft = torpedoesLeft - 1;
    cout << "Torpedoes: " << torpedoesLeft << endl;

    cout << "Ships Destroyed: " << shipsDestroyed << endl << endl;
}//End of torpedoes
```

Answer (score 0):

The workflow of the code is a little bit strange...
But, at least, I see the error over here:

```
while((shipsDestroyed != 5) && (torpedoesLeft != 0))
```

Reason: you are creating first battleship object named "B1" in main function.  In battleship::newGame() you are creating the game object which is inherrited from battleship. And you are working with G1 inside of the cycle but checking fields "torpedoesLeft" and "shipsDestroyed" of object B1!

One of the possible solutions:

```
while((G1.shipsDestroyed != 5) && (G1.torpedoesLeft != 0))
```

and make this field public (but it's very bad, it's better to read about inheritance and incapsulation and refactor this code, also it will be good to use contructors instead of methods constrructGame, newBattleship)

Comment: Wow, such simple things I always miss. Thank you for that, it worked to break the loop. All i got to figure out now is this +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, so I'll just tell you what's happening.

In `main`

```
battleship B1;
B1.newBattleship();
```

you're creating a `battleship` instance, and telling it to start a new "battleship".

```
void battleship::newBattleship()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the game of Battleship!\n\n";
    battleship game;
    game.newGame();
}
```

This creates a different `battleship` instance and tells it to start a new game

```
void battleship::newGame()
{
    Game G1;

    G1.constructGame(0,45);

    G1.setupBoard();
    G1.outputBoard();

    do
    {
        G1.torpedoes();
        G1.outputBoard();
    }while((shipsDestroyed != 5) && (torpedoesLeft != 0));
}
```

and *that* instace creates an instance of `Game` and uses that to run the game.

All these instances (there are three at this point) have their own member variables, all distinct from the others'.

So

```
while((shipsDestroyed != 5) && (torpedoesLeft != 0));
```

checks its own variables, not those belonging to `G1`.

It's possible that you want `G1.getTorpedoesLeft()` and `G1.getShipsDestroyed()`, but it's not entirely clear what your intention is.

Side note:

```
if((row == row) && (column == column))
```

is always true.

Comment: I dont want every spot to equal X as i want only hits to be X

Comment: @Justin Oh, they were hard-coded ships. I missed that part.

Comment: Do you know of a way for me to not have to make a big if statement to make it not add 1 each time it loops? Its confusing to explain but I hope you kind of get what this problem is.